Php CURL cookie with 24-hour session
I have a curl script that takes data from my personal account on another site, the problem is that the script works only 24 hours (the session on the site is set to 24 hours), when 24 hours pass my script no longer works and I get a response that the session is out of date. how do I update the session in curl every 24 hours?

$ch = curl_init();
$post_field = 'ajax=SearchArticulo&cntrSgn=DeExMEkRabGEO396gOLDMqUZiXe2BibRjqgUXwZlQmMgrw4jJmdAwbUD11%2BddBhn&srcInicio=false&isSimple=false&codMarca=0&field=nombre&value=&oferta=false&pvpSubido=False&detallada=false&codPedido=';
$post_field .= '&cat1=5&cat2=65&cat3=363&token=';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://actibios.com/WebForms/Clientes/GenerarPedidosVentas_new.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://actibios.com/WebForms/Clientes/GenerarPedidosVentas_new.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modules/heallyimport/cookie_actibios.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modules/heallyimport/cookie_actibios.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Keep-Alive'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$table_array = array();
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $row_array = array();
        foreach ($cols as $col) {

            $row_array[] = $col->nodeValue;
        }
        $table_array[] = $row_array;
    }
}

$products = [];
foreach ($table_array as &$item) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://actibios.com/WebForms/Clientes/Indicacion.aspx?cp='.$item[0]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ajax=GetIndicacion&codArticulo=".$item[0]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modules/heallyimport/cookie_actibios.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modules/heallyimport/cookie_actibios.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://actibios.com/WebForms/Clientes/GenerarPedidosVentas_new.aspx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
    $page_content = preg_replace('/<(pre)(?:(?!<\/\1).)*?<\/\1>/s','',curl_exec($ch));
    $desc = explode(':',$page_content);

    $description = str_replace(",'marca'","",$desc[3]);
    $description = str_replace("'", "", $description);
    $name = str_replace("\xc2\xa0",' ',$item[1]);
    $name = trim($name);

    $products[] = [
        'ref' => $item[0],
        'name' => $name,
        'cat1' => 'COSMÉTICA E HIGIENE',
        'cat2' => 'Salud bucodental',
        'cat3' => 'Hilo dental e interdentales',
        'image' => 'https://actibios.com/WebForms/Controls/imgArticulo.aspx?ca='.$item[0],
        'stock' => $item[5],
        'desc' => $description,
        'brand' => $item[2],
        'price1' => floatval($item[6]),
        'price2' => floatval($item[7])
    ];
    unset($item[8]);
    unset($item[9]);
    unset($item[10]);
}
echo json_encode($products); ```


my cookie file

actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   SERVERUSED  srv1|ZjTjo|ZjTjn
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1716788903  grpAct@CnfCookies=%7B%22chkNecesarias%22%3A%221%22%2C%22chkRendimiento%22%3A%221%22%2C%22chkFuncionalidad%22%3A%221%22%2C%22chkPublicidad%22%3A%221%22%7D   
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@User E33242342342342348029
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@Lang 1
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@Pwd  XwIXxTl5oxgV2xsddsfdsfsfsedo8wrPA==
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1714826791  grpAct@Session  Dtvr1JiluA9LIHeeZ5ouvnMpCOoa4jukvPHkP8WLoC6NMC9eZtHc4tArv7CVLPLs9tw0AqlIJRwisfZAdddddddddddddddddddddddddddIBCbMKFDHNdFkwH83ZcHJL6CU5KAOcHwM8KJESLEWg5o0bi51qDA%2FRLgMrNk%2BcSvBYUh0vN0W1d90bjUJB4Vs3IAtX6kHG4GFl3bUK0N5DM1iYeQ4jLffrp5mGNVgYsTNUlXCA5T8%2FAKyK%2FKUwJkt5e6lPcIujQS7xVNU4EssKdcVFetisHo1vMAq%2BLiorTPs43pA87CWCH7k%3D
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@Version  2024.01.25.005
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@Year 
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@CodDelegacion    1
actibios.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1717415191  grpAct@CodEmpresa   1



and problem with grpAct@Session


Are you sure the destination server allows sessions >24 hours?

@MarkusZeller Yes, exactly after 24 hours the script stops working and I see in the cookie file that the session has expired. I also looked at the cookie of this site in the browser and it says that the session is valid only one day.

But that does not answer my question. When the server does not grant a session >24 h why don't you implement a login after expiration?

@MarkusZeller that's the question, how i can do that and get new data with session?

You can read the cookie file and know when the session is over or via checking the response. Just mimic the login process. Do it with the browser and watch the network tab to see what is sent.

@MarkusZeller how i can do it? can you give an example code?

You can code by yourself as you've already shown. Login process usually is a post request.

Submitting the login form on https://actibios.com causes an AJAX POST request to https://actibios.com/Home with the parameters ajax=ValidarUser&codEmpresa=1&txtUser=...&txtPwd=...&hidLang=0&chkRecordar=0, so likely that is the request you will have to mimic, to get a new valid session ID. (Whether you can just send this data, or need to make a request to get some initial cookie values first, you'd have to check.)
